# Which design pattern can be used in case of two class having common fields so that we don't need to create new Class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns

In a spring boot application, I return a **UserResponseDTO** in the first api as below

```
public class UserReponseDTO{
  private Long Id,
  private String field1,
  private String field2,
  private String field3,
  private String field4,
  private String field5,
  private String field6,
  
//setters and getters...
}
```

But as per the requirement of a second API, I  need to return response DTO having 2 more fields.

```
public class NewReponseDTO{
  private Long Id,
  private String field1,
  private String field2,
  private String field3,
  private String field4,
  private String field5,
  private String field6,
 
  //new fields
  private String fields7,
  private String fields8
 
 //setters and getters...
}
```

Which design pattern can be used so that I can add new fields on runtime in ***UserResponseDTO*** instead of creating new responseDTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use extends keyword example

```
public class UserReponseDTO{
  private Long Id,
  private String field1,
  private String field2,
  private String field3,
  private String field4,
  private String field5,
  private String field6,
  
//setters and getters...
}
```

Now define the new class

```
public class NewReponseDTO extends UserReponseDTO{
private String fields7,
  private String fields8
 
 //setters and getters..
}
```

now u don't have to re-define the already defined variables